# Highcharts pie color of a part when i click on this

Tags: jquery, api, highcharts, pie-chart

How can i modify this code http://jsfiddle.net/r6p7E/6/ to see the section selected with the same color everytime i will select ?  I want this to be yellow only when i will click on this.

Code :

```
  $(function () {

            Highcharts.theme = {
            colors: ['#242c4a'],
            chart: {
             width: 350,
                backgroundColor: {
                    linearGradient: [0, 0, 500, 500],
                    stops: [
                        [0, 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'],
                        [1, 'rgb(240, 240, 255)']
                    ]
                }, 
            },

        };

        // Apply the theme
        Highcharts.setOptions(Highcharts.theme);

        // Build the chart
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Our Projects'
            },

            plotOptions: {

                pie: {


                    borderColor: '#48588c',
                    borderWidth: 7,
                     slicedOffset: 10,                     
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false

                    }

                },

                series: {

                point: {
                    events: {
                        select: function() {

                        }
                    }
                }
            }


            },
              series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                name: 'Browser share',
                dashStyle: 'LongDashDotDot',
                data: [
                    ['Firefox',   45.0],
                    ['IE',       26.8],
                    {
                        name: 'Chrome',
                        y: 12.8,
                        sliced: true,
                        selected: true
                    },
                    ['Safari',    8.5],
                    ['Opera',     6.2],
                    ['Others',   0.7]
                ]
            }]
        },

         function(chart) { // on complete


        var renderer = new Highcharts.Renderer(
            $('#container')[0],  50, 50);

        chart.renderer.circle(175, 216, 22).attr({
            fill: '#e7e620',

            'stroke-width': 5,
            zIndex: 3
        }).add();
        }



        );
    });
```

Comment: Are you saying that you don't want the color to change when you hover, you only want it to change when you click?  Also, do you want all pieces to be the same color (yellow) when you click, or would you like each piece to be it's own color?

Comment: I want the piece on which i click to be yellow and the others don't change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be what you actually want. But based on what you asked for this fiddle gives you that: http://jsfiddle.net/r6p7E/8/

Instead of a mouseOver event, you can change that to a click event:

```
point: {
    events: {
        click: function () {
            this.graphic.attr({
                fill: 'yellow'
            });
        }
    }
},
```

Of course the mouseOut event kills the color once you move away but I am not sure if that is what you desire or not as you didn't mention it.

EDIT: This fiddle retains the color of yellow until it is unselected (or another is selected): http://jsfiddle.net/r6p7E/12/

```
allowPointSelect: true,
slicedOffset: 0,
point: {
    events: {
        select: function () {
            this.update({color: 'yellow'});
        },
        unselect: function () {
            this.update({color: '#CCCCCC'});
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to keep the color even if the mouse cursor is not over pie.

Comment: slicedOffset : 0 - keeps the pie slice from sliding out

Comment: Brilliant! I didn't notice that option. I updated my answer to include it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L5SXX/

You need to turn on allowPointSelect and then add the color for the select state.  Because you're doing the mouseOver and mouseOut stuff, you need some modifications to keep the selected color.

```
    plotOptions: {

        series: {
            allowPointSelect : true,
            slicedOffset: 0,
            states: {
                select: {
                    color: 'yellow'
                },
                hover: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            },
            point: {
                events: {
                    mouseOver: function () {
                        this.graphic.attr({
                            fill: 'red'
                        });
                    }
                }
            },
            events: {
                mouseOut: function () {
                    var serie = this.points;

                    $.each(serie, function (i, e) {
                        if (!this.selected) {                                    
                            this.graphic.attr({
                                fill: '#CCCCCC'
                            });
                        }
                        else {
                             this.graphic.attr({
                                fill: 'yellow'
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but how can i keep the selected color?

Comment: This code returns it to the selected color after mouse out.  Do you want it to be yellow even on mouse over?  If so, add an if (!this.selected) to the mouseOver code to not change the color for selected pieces.